# Import field in XML using SQL not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

i've been trying to import the field GivenName in my example XML but for some reason it's not working, i've been using the following SQL query, i think i'm using the correct field and the correct nodes but i'm not 100% sure about the XMLNameSpaces

Thank you very much in advance for your help

This is the example SQL Query i'm using:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = (SELECT [Xml] FROM ExampleTable)

 ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05','http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope' )

select FirstName = ProfileInfo.value('Profiles[1]/ProfileInfo[1]/Profile[1]/Customer[1]/PersonName[1]/@GivenName', 'nvarchar(255)')
    FROM @xml.nodes('Envelope/Body/OTA_Example/Info/Infos/ResUser') as T1(Profiles) 
      outer apply T1.Profiles.nodes('ResUser2') as T2(ProfileInfo)
```

This is the example XML i'm using for the import:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap2:Header xmlns:htng="http://htng.org/1.3/Header/" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" 
  xmlns:wss="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
  xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:htnga="http://htng.org/PWSWG/2007/02/AsyncHeaders" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
  xmlns:soap2="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <wsa:Action>Example</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:ReplyTo>
      <wsa:Address>Example2</wsa:Address>
    </wsa:ReplyTo>
    <htnga:ReplyTo>
      <wsa:Address>Example3</wsa:Address>
    </htnga:ReplyTo>
    <wsa:MessageID>123</wsa:MessageID>
    </soap2:Header>
  <Body>
    <OTA_Example xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" Version="5.000" >
      <Info>
        <Infos CreateDateTime="2021-09-20T06:52:40" CreatorID="User">
          <UniqueID Type="1" ID="12341251" />
           <ResUser>
            <ResUser2 ResGuestRPH="1" PrimaryIndicator="true">
              <Profiles>
                <ProfileInfo>
                    <Profile ProfileType="1">
                    <Customer>
                      <PersonName>
                        <NamePrefix>Mr.</NamePrefix>
                        <GivenName>FirstnameTest</GivenName>
                        <Surname>LastnameTest</Surname>
                      </PersonName>
                      </Customer>
                  </Profile>
                </ProfileInfo>
              </Profiles>
            </ResUser2>
          </ResUser>
         </Infos>
      </Info>
    </OTA_Example>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: How many `ResUser` nodes do you expect (or any other of its parent nodes)?

Comment: just one ResUser node (same goes for the parent nodes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GivenName` is not an attribute, so you shouldn't use `@` for it.

It's unclear why you needed `.nodes`, it is only needed if there were multiple nodes that needed breaking out into separate rows

You can also select straight out of `ExampleTable`, you do not need to store it in a variable.

```sql
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (
   'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope' AS soap,
   DEFAULT 'http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05')

select FirstName = [XML].value('(soap:Envelope/soap:Body/OTA_Example/Info/Infos/ResUser/ResUser2/Profiles/ProfileInfo/Profile/Customer/PersonName/GivenName/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(255)')
    FROM ExampleTable
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=56de4725d09d973ba912389a5428127a)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Charlieface,
Ah yeah you're right about the atrribute, i missed that.

The example i posted is part of a much bigger XML (there are parts where there are multiple nodes) and it's necessary to use .nodes there.

Comment: but i was now able to adapt my Query using your solution and help and now it's working :)

Comment: just did it (can't upvote it because i don't have enough reputation points yet but i clicked on the check mark), Thanks again